# Calinski-Harabasz cluster evaluation

Tags: clustering, matlab

[image]I have used K-mean algorithm for clustering my data , and i have used   Calinski-Harabasz as validity index measurement, the value of CH are :

```
 k=2 , CH= 13.41,  well separated cluster 
 k=4 , CH= 269.68   overlapped cluster
```

The figure is k-mean algorithm with k=2 and CH= 13.41 
and the second one is k-mean algorithm with k=4 , and CH = 269.68

i have added the 3rd figure in which the cluster are not separated well  and the
CH = 729 ??

[image]

the K=2  and the first figure is separated well cluster , while the second one is nonseparated well cluster

any suggestion please iam confused with CH behavior.

Comment: There is a bouquet of questions to your case. 1) Were you doing K-means on the initial data or the two principal components you show? 2) Same Q about you doing CH calculation. 3) Your PC1 is so overwhelmingly bigger variance than PC2 that one wonders how you managed to get such clear oblong clusters by K-means. Did you standardize the data first? 4) If yes did you do same with computation of CH? Btw it is nice to give the data and to show the annotated code you used.

Comment: @  ttnphns : iam working on the PC's data , Why CH  increasing when i increased the k number ?

Comment: You didn't answer other points. In particular, (3). It is impossible to get 2 clusters like you showed with K-means because it produces approximately spherical clusters but your PCs are _very_ different variance. So, did you standardize them before the clustering. If yes, why not show the standardized PCs? Did you compute CH on the standardized PCs either? (you should have to!)

Comment: @ttphns the data are normalized before the analyse

Comment: OK then you ought to plot the pictures of the normalized data. Is CH computed on on _those_ data problematic to you? If yes, may we ask you to post (or link to) the (normalized and clustered) dataset so that we could try to compute CH, to check?

Answer (score 1):

The problem are your *plots*.

Avoid plotting with **distortion**. If you plotted the data such that 1 unit on the x axis has the same size as 1 uniton the y axis, the result would likely be more comprehensible.

In your example, imagine the plot to be squeezed!

[image]

compared to

[image]

clearly, the bottom one does not separate the clusters well. The *width* of the clusters (about 40) is much larger than the separation between the cluster centers (about 2). In the top picture, thr width of the clusters is about 25,and the distance is over 10; so the top result *is* much better.

**Don't let yourself be fooled by distorted plots!**

I understand that the *intuition* here is different; but then you need to preprocess the data differently. As is, the distances clearly show the first result to be better.